# ASP.NET Core MVC : Keycloak error on Signin-oidc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I use keycloak in an ASP.NET Core 7.0 MVC app, but when I go in the login page I get this error:

> Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.
>
> Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Code:

```
//authentication
builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CommonConsts.UserAuthenticationPolicyScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
       .AddCookie(CommonConsts.UserAuthenticationCookieScheme, options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/signin-oidc/";

                // Handle unauthorized call on api with 401 response. For already logged in users.
                options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    else
                        context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            })
       .AddJwtBearer(CommonConsts.UserAuthenticationJwtScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://kyklos-dev-keycloak.azurewebsites.net/auth/realms/MYAPP-DEV";
                options.Audience = "MYAPP-DEV-api";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
                    //RoleClaimType = roleClaimType,
                };
                options.TokenValidationParameters = validationParameters;
            })
       .AddPolicyScheme(CommonConsts.UserAuthenticationPolicyScheme, CommonConsts.UserAuthenticationPolicyScheme, options =>
            {
                //runs on each request
                options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
                {
                    //filter by auth type
                    string authorization = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization]!;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization) && authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        return CommonConsts.UserAuthenticationJwtScheme;

                    //otherwise always check for cookie auth
                    return CommonConsts.UserAuthenticationCookieScheme;
                };
            })
       .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = CommonConsts.UserAuthenticationPolicyScheme;
                options.ClientId = "MYAPP-DEV-web";
                options.Authority = "https://kyklos-dev-keycloak.azurewebsites.net/auth/realms/MYAPP-DEV";

                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;

                options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc";
                options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-oidc";

                // Handle unauthorized call on api with 401 response. For users not logged in.
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                        context.HandleResponse();
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            });
```

Curiosity: if I remove the `app.UseAuthentication();` I go in the login landing page and I can insert my login (but without that my auth page not working :D )